# How to hide file from list in directory

Tags: php

I have a script file. that list files and folder in a directory.. I want to hide certain files and folder. How do I do that?

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") 
         && ($file != ".."))
        {
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>

<P>List of files:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

Comment: Do you know the names of the files beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$files_to_hide = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt');
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && !in_array($file, $files_to_hide))
        {
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>

<P>List of files:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to not add `"."` and `".."` to that `$file_to_hide` array?

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of filenames you want to exclude in an array.

After that, you check whether the filename [exists in the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) before adding it to `$thelist`.

You can add that as part of the `if()` statement that checks if the filename is `.` or `..`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$bannedFiles = Array(".", "..", "example");
if ($handle = opendir('.')){
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        $banned = false;
        foreach ($bannedFiles as $bFile){
            if ($bFile == $file){
                $banned = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$banned){
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></LI>';
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>

<P>List of files:</p>
<UL>
<P><? echo $thelist;?></p>
</UL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of the files/directories you want to hide, you can maintain a set-map of such entries, and filter them out within the while loop.

Your set-map would look like this:

```
$items_to_hide = [ "/home/me/top_secret" => 1, "/home/me/passwords.txt" => 1, ... ]
```

And then you would modfiy your while loop like this:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
    // check map if said file is supposed to be hidden, if so skip current loop iteration
    if($items_to_hide[$file]) {
      continue;
    }
    if (($file != ".") 
     && ($file != ".."))
    {
        $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Also wanted to mention, using a php ordered array as your "blacklist" is quite efficient, as a single lookup will occur in almost constant time. Hence you can grow your blacklist as large as you want and still see decent performance.